# problem with emit from socket.io (server to client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm having a problem with socket.io at the moment I try to send a second time from the server to the client

here is the server code with express and socket.io

```js
io.on('connection',  async function (socket) {
    let socketId = socket.id;
    const mta = new Client("20.64.24.144", 22005, "*", "*");
    
    mta.resources.evokestats.getPlayerCount()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("result", result);
            socket.emit("players-start", { players: result })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Ooops! Something went wrong ${err}`);
        });

    app.post('/player_connect', async function (req, res) {
        let ip = req.body[0];
        let player = await players.findOne({ ip: ip })

        if (player) {
            await socket.emit("players", { players: req.body[1] })
        } else {

            try {
                player = await players.create({ ip: ip, name: req.body[2] })
                await socket.emit("players", { players: req.body[1] })
                await socket.emit("last_24_players", { players: 1 });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error", error)
            }

        }


        res.send("connected")
    });
    });
```

and here is my client with reactjs and socket.io

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        getStats();
    }, [])

   async function getStats(params) {
   
      

       socket.on("players-start", function (data) {
           setNowPlayers(data.players)
       });

       socket.on("players", function (data) {
           console.log("players", data)
           setNowPlayers(data.players)
       });});
```

And in my client using react, in useEffect I listen to the "players-start" and the "players" that was emit.

players-start: It is for every first time that I enter my client he only calls once, to bring all players connected

players: Every time someone connects to the game server, a post call is made to my server where I use the express with socket, in the url '/player_connect' and then immediately emit

The problem: whenever I issue an issue on 'players-start' and then immediately enter the game server that calls the url '/player_connect' it is not triggering the issue of 'players' or at least the client is not receiving.

Test I've done:
My first attempt was to stick everything to the listener "players" but it still doesn’t work

I really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Your socket events in the client will be attached only once after the component has mounted. Could it be that the server is emitting the event before this happens?

Comment: not this one, I checked it, it really only calls after I make the call from my game server to the url